# alguem sabe porque esse erro no ionic

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova

Utilizando o Fedora e aparece esse erro alguém sabe resolver

```
Running command - failed!

[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):

    (truncated) ... roid.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 >
    com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools:sdklib:25.2.3 >
    com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:25.2.3
    > Could not resolve net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0.
    > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.pom'.
    > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException:
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-1.b12.fc25.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)
    > Could not resolve net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0.
    > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.pom'.
    > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException:
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-1.b12.fc25.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)
    > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:5.0.4.
    Required by:
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 >
    com.android.tools.lint:lint:25.2.3 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:25.2.3
    > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:5.0.4.
    > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/5.0.4/asm-analysis-5.0.4.pom'.
    > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException:
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-1.b12.fc25.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)
    > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:5.0.4.
    > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/5.0.4/asm-analysis-5.0.4.pom'.
    > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException:
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-1.b12.fc25.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)
    > Could not resolve com.intellij:annotations:12.0.
    Required by:
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 >
    com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools:sdklib:25.2.3 >
    com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:25.2.3
    > Could not resolve com.intellij:annotations:12.0.
    > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/intellij/annotations/12.0/annotations-12.0.pom'.
    > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException:
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-1.b12.fc25.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)
    > Could not resolve com.intellij:annotations:12.0.
    > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/intellij/annotations/12.0/annotations-12.0.pom'.
    > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException:
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-1.b12.fc25.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)
    > Could not resolve com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1.
    Required by:
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 >
    com.android.tools.build:builder:2.2.3 > com.android.tools:sdklib:25.2.3 > com.android.tools:repository:25.2.3
    > Could not resolve com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1.
    > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/jimfs/jimfs/1.1/jimfs-1.1.pom'.
    > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException:
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-1.b12.fc25.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)
    > Could not resolve com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1.
    > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/jimfs/jimfs/1.1/jimfs-1.1.pom'.
    > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException:
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-1.b12.fc25.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)
    > Could not resolve com.android.tools.external.lombok:lombok-ast:0.2.3.
    Required by:
    project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.2.3 >
    com.android.tools.lint:lint:25.2.3 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:25.2.3 >
    com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:25.2.3
    > Could not resolve com.android.tools.external.lombok:lombok-ast:0.2.3.
    > Could not get resource
    'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/external/lombok/lombok-ast/0.2.3/lombok-ast-0.2.3.pom'.
    > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException:
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-1.b12.fc25.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)
    > Could not resolve com.android.tools.external.lombok:lombok-ast:0.2.3.
    > Could not get resource
    'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/lombok/lombok-ast/0.2.3/lombok-ast-0.2.3.pom'.
    > org.apache.http.ssl.SSLInitializationException:
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-1.b12.fc25.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts (No such file or directory)

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Comment: Ja execultou npm prune e npm install?

Comment: O install sim, depois vou executar o npm prune e vê o que acontece, obrigado